# Нужно сделать шару на линуксе не используя SAMBA

Tags: linux, администрирование, share, сетевое-администрирование

Нельзя использовать самбу потому что на сервере реализован контроллер домен с помощью самбы и она не дает расшарить папку с файловой системой NTFS потому что на нее нельзя навесить ACL.

Нужно просто реализовать сетевую папку для бэкапа.

Есть вариант через консоль с рутом прописать в настройки самбы сетевую папку. И она даже будет работать, но после перезагрузки написанная настройка дропается из файла конфигурации.

Вопрос: Есть ли альтернативные программы для расшаривания сетевой папки на линуксе?

Comment: Ну, банальный sftp, наверное? (Не путать с ftps)

Comment: а что NFS не подходит ?

Comment: `sshfs` - тоже вполне ок.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, можно использовать ssh/sftp.

> Есть вариант через консоль с рутом прописать в настройки самбы сетевую папку. И она даже будет работать, но после перезагрузки написанная настройка дропается из файла конфигурации.

Сброс настроек при перезагрузке, скорее всего, связан с отсутствием автоматического монтирования папки при старте системы.

Можете попробовать настроить монтирование по этому гайду для астры https://fast-wolker.ru/kak-sozdat-setevuyu-papku-na-linuks-astra.html
Обратите внимание на пункт "Как  настроить автоматические монтирование  сетевой  папки в Астра Линукс?".

Comment: Автомонтирование есть. Настройка дропается потому что контроллер домена не любит когда лапают его файлы =( 
Это наверное система защиты такая.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли альтернативные программы для расшаривания сетевой папки на
> линуксе?

На Linux не нужно ничего расшаривать, можно просто копировать настроив права.(ssh)